# Ubuntu 19.04 applications loading way too long

Tags: updates, dell, 19.04, bug-reporting, xps

Unsure if this is the place to ask, but recently I installed Ubuntu 19.04 on to my Dell XPS 13 9360 laptop. Pretty much everything runs perfectly smooth, except that certain applications such as the calculator or software center take forever to load.

If anyone else has experienced it, is there any way I could reproduce it to file a bug report or maybe get some type of fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a few applications like `gnome-calculator` and `gnome-system-monitor` are actually snap apps. The delay is a known issue of snap apps. A workaround is to remove snap apps and replace them by `apt` ones.

You can get a list of your installed snaps running

```
snap list
```

You can remove a snap app running

```
snap remove <snap-name>
```

To install an `apt` app run

```
sudo apt install <apt-name>
```

`<apt-name>` is usually the same as the `<snap-name>`

Comment: Thank you, this worked well.